# I want the photo to slide down when hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css

when there are more 'gy-section', when you hover over them, only the first photo moves and the rest do not want to work

I tried changing classes, adding other classes, converting them to id, changing the JS code but nothing works.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="gy-section">
                <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
let gyHover = this.document.querySelector(".gy-section");
let gySection = this.document.querySelector(".gy-sec-img");
let gyText = this.document.querySelector(".gy-simg-title");

let value = '';

gyHover.addEventListener('mouseenter', async function up() {
  value = gySection.backgroundPositionY;

  gySection.animate([
        // key frames
        { backgroundPositionY: {value} },
        { backgroundPositionY: '100%'}
      ], {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        iterations: 1,
    });

    gyHover.classList.add('gys-hover');
    gySection.classList.add('gys-hover');
    gyText.classList.add('gst-hover');
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3999)); // 3 sec
    gySection.style.backgroundPositionY = "100%";
});

gyHover.addEventListener('mouseleave', async function down() {
  value = gySection.backgroundPositionY;

  gySection.animate([
        // key frames
        { backgroundPositionY: {value} },
        { backgroundPositionY: '0%'}
      ], {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        iterations: 1,
    });

    gyHover.classList.remove('gys-hover');
    gySection.classList.remove('gys-hover');
    gyText.classList.remove('gst-hover');
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3999)); // 3 sec
    gySection.style.backgroundPositionY = "0%";
});
```

Comment: The `queryselector` returns the first element. May be using `queryselectorall` helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
    const imgArr = [
    document.getElementById('img-height-1'),
    document.getElementById('img-height-2'),
    document.getElementById('img-height-3'),
    document.getElementById('img-height-4'),
];

for(let i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    
    imgArr[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {

        const imgScrollHeight = imgArr[i].scrollHeight - img.scrollHeight;

        console.log('0px ' + imgScrollHeight + 'px');
        imgArr[i].style.translate = '0px -' + imgScrollHeight + 'px';

    });

    imgArr[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {

        const imgScrollHeight = imgArr[i].scrollHeight - img.scrollHeight;

        console.log('0px ' + imgScrollHeight + 'px');
        imgArr[i].style.translate = '0px 0px';

    });

}
```

Just have to change JS and add ID to img in html.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a solution which doesn't utilize JavaScript:

```css
.gy-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: 15px;
}

.gy-sec-img {
  background: url('https://s.imgur.com/images/logo-1200-630.jpg?2');
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.gy-sec-img:hover {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gy-section">
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gy-section">
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gy-section">
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
      <div class="gy-sec-img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```